# Error when uploading plugin to JetBrains Plugin Repository

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I am trying to deploy my plugin to the JetBrains Plugin Repository, But getting the following error-

> ID of edited plugin is null, but uploaded plugin has
>   ID="package_name". You can not change id of plugin!

However I have ensured the `<id>package id </id>` has not changed.
And also I am uploading this for first time.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Here is the plugin.xml-

```
<idea-plugin version="3">
    <id>my package name</id>
    <name>My Plugin Name</name>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <vendor email="support@skedsoft.com" url="http://www.skedsoft.com">SkedSoft</vendor>

    <description><![CDATA[
      plugin description
    ]]></description>

    <change-notes><![CDATA[
      plgin change details
    ]]>
    </change-notes>

    <!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html for description -->
    <idea-version since-build="141.0"/>

    <!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
         on how to target different products -->
    <!-- uncomment to enable plugin in all products

    -->
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.androidstudio</depends>
    <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- Add your extensions here -->
    </extensions>

    <actions>
        my action classes and details
    </actions>

</idea-plugin>
```

Comment: Post the actual plugin.xml, or ask jetbrains.

Comment: Hey meo, I have added the plugin.xml please have a look.
Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you should upload/release the plugin with correctly filled informations... that includes the ID, which I doubt allows whitespaces.

Comment: And why do you have there version="3"? it should be always "2"

Comment: Id is not having white space. I also tried with version="2" @ Meo

Comment: Still not solved? Why don't you write an email to  plugins-admin at jetbrains.com ?

Comment: I have written them twice and did not get response. Its more than 4 days. :(

Comment: they always helped me quickly :(

Comment: It seems we encounter the same issue. Even the default demo plugin can't be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with plugin repository. You can upload your plugin now.